# Positive signed tick labels in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

How is it possible to get a positive +-sign in front of the y tick labels in a matplotlib subplot?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick and dirty (I'd say that methods' names are self-explanatory, aren't they?)

```
ax = plt.gca()
ylabels = ax.get_ylabels()
for ylabel in ylabels: ylabel.set_text('+'+ylabel.get_text()) 
ax.set_ylabels(ylabels)
```

A little more kosher

```
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
...
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FormatStrFormatter("%+g"))
plt.plot(...)
...
```

The second part has been written using https://matplotlib.org/gallery/ticks_and_spines/tick-formatters.html as a reference.

---

*Addendum*

In a comment the OP asked *"… what can I do to avoid a +-sign in front of the 0?"*.

A possible solution can be

```
...
bare0 = lambda y, pos: ('%+g' if y>0 else '%g')%y
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(bare0))
...
```

See https://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter for the details.

Comment: The kosher method is nice! But what can I do to avoid a +-sign in front of the 0?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe like this ?

```
plt.yticks(np.arange(6), ('0', '+1', '+2', '+3', '+4', '+5'))
```